# Eagerly validate set of form elements with jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with elements `#a`, `#b` and `#c`. The validation I need to enforce is require `#a || (#b && #c)` (i.e. fill in `#a` or both of `#b` and `#c` or all three). I've got `required` and the dependencies working:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var AorBandC = function() {
    var hasA = $("#a").val().trim().length > 0;
    var hasBandC = $("#b").val().trim().length > 0 &&
      $("#c").val().trim().length > 0;

    return !(hasA || hasBandC);
  };

  var validator = $("#myform").validate({
    validClass: "valid",
    errorClass: "invalid",
    rules: {
      a: {
        required: AorBandC
      },
      b: {
        required: AorBandC
      },
      c: {
        required: AorBandC
      }
    },
    messages: {
      a: "",
      b: "",
      c: ""
    }
  });
  
  // this code manually validates all related controls
  $("#a").keyup(function() {
    validator.element("#b");
    validator.element("#c");
  });
  $("#b").keyup(function() {
    validator.element("#a");
    validator.element("#c");
  });
  $("#c").keyup(function() {
    validator.element("#a");
    validator.element("#b");
  });

  $("#myform").valid();
});
```

```css
input.invalid {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: 4px solid red;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
input.valid {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: 4px solid green;
  padding-left: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post" id="myform">
  A <input type="text" id="a" name="a" />
  <br/>
  B <input type="text" id="b" name="b" />
  <br/>
  C <input type="text" id="c" name="c" />
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" text="Submit" />
</form>
```

The issue I'm having is that as soon as I've got a valid input, I'd like to show all now optional inputs as valid, but that only happens manually by tabbing through, or with the bit of code at the end, which feels like a bit of a hack. `keypress` and `keydown` had issues in that the non-active elements would only get validated on the second keystroke and `change` only fires on blur, both of which don't update until the user tabs out of the input element.

Surely there's a better way to achieve the same thing? The `require_from_group` method doesn't appear to be able to handle this situation.

Comment: If I was the user, it would feel obtrusive as it keeps alerting me what's next. Requirement of dynamic fill-in is very common in today's world. So why not build a friendlier and intuitive dynamic show/hide?

Comment: a) because I'm stuck with a particular form design/layout in a legacy app, b) I've edited the snippet to remove the messages and more closely reflect the actual use, c) I think this is pretty friendly and intuitive

Comment: Your code is working, thanks to your `keyup` handlers, so I don't understand the question.  If you want to know if there is a better way, maybe `require_from_group`, otherwise, I see nothing wrong with your approach.

Comment: @Sparky Yes, it works but I was hoping that somebody could point me to something built-in to the plugin since I find my solution to be a bit inelegant. `require_from_group` only seems to handle an at least one-of situation.